# accelerate pairwise force calculation in cuda C++

Tags: performance, memory, cuda, pairwise

recently I write a Molecular Dynamics code calculating the ion-electron force using CUDA parallel computing.
the kernel is list as below:

```
__global__ void (*x,*y,*z,N){
    int i = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    while(i<N) {
        double dx;
        double dy;
        double dz;
        double dr;
        double Fx;
        double Fy;
        double Fz;

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            dx=x[i]-x[j];
            dy=y[i]-y[j];
            dz=z[i]-z[j];
            dr=sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz) 
            dr=dr*dr*dr
            Fx+=k*q*q*dx/dr
            Fy+=k*q*q*dy/dr
            Fz+=k*q*q*dz/dr        //force=kq^2r/r^3 written in Cartesian coordinate
            }
        //rest of the code manipulate force is irrelevant to my question and I want to keep my code short
        i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

x,y,z are position of the particels, and dx,dy,dz is the xyz distance, Fx, Fy, Fz in the for loop is the sum of force exerting on ith particle, more specifically you need to calculate x[i]-x[j] and run through all js to find the total force, and let the kernel do all i in parallel.

I found this to be slow as I know the GPU is reading the arrays from global memory. When I change x[i] to a number it becomes 10 times faster because it is reading from the register(L1 cache). my array is too big (more than 20000 element with double float) it is impossible to put into the register. But can it still be a little faster using other memories? I know there's constant memory and shared memory but I don't know how to implement. I think the x[i] is sitting at the globe memory causing it to be slow, and all thread is trying to read x[i] at the same time. any way to improve the speed?

Comment: I would be worrying about correctness rather than performance. There is no way that your code is computing repeatable, correct results. It doesn’t even store anything to global memory, meaning that if you compile the code with optimisation on, it should compile to an empty kernel with zero execution time

Comment: I do change my code when I'm posting this, the original one is long and need more careful treatment for those variables and algorithm, sorry just show part of my code and it is oversimplified, the Fx Fy and Fz defiantly needs to be stored somewhere and I miss that part. my question is each thread is reading the same x[i] N times and reading x[j] N^2 times because of the loop. is there any way to reduce the times it reads the same variable or speed up reading the variable

Comment: A blockwise tiling approach would work fine. Basically treat i and j as if they were rows and columns in a matrix. Use the same blockwise evaluation scheme that is used to optimize matrix-matrix multiplications. I might write a proper answer later, if I find the time

Comment: hey Homer512: I would see both algorithm work if memory reading and writing is optimized(both require same amount of reading). for other reasons I choose the one I present here, mainly because I don't need to save all xi-xj element like calculating the xi-xj matrix does, but just let Fx rewrite itself so it save huge memory space. I'm targeting at 50k particles if saving this matrixes will take more than 40G memory space. I tried without using share memory before and it is slower than the method I present here so I gave up. if possible I would like to stick to the way I calculate now.

Comment: What point is there in posting uncompilable, broken code and asking about optimization strategies? Details matter

Comment: Note that in such N-body code, it is very common to assume that some force are negligible because of the `1 / dr` factor being very small for "long" distances (it decreases with a rate of `O(1 / (n^3))`). Because of that, you can often discard a big part of the computation and not store it. Quad-tree and AMR methods help to do that (though it is not simple). Besides, it is generally not a good idea to store the result: you need to compute it on the fly to get a fast code. Memory is much slower than computing units nowadays and it is not gonna be better any time soon (quite the opposite).

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately the simulation project I'm working on could not neglect the long distance force. there are approximation algorithm we are familiar with, but it has its own downside. By the way I agree that the memory bandwidth or speed might take years to meet specific project requirements.

Comment: Ok. Note that you can aggregate the influence of many particles with grid-based methods. The idea is to accumulate the mass of all particle of a cell and find its centre of mass. Once computed, you can consider all the particles of a cell to be 1 big particle when it is far enough. It is like considering all the molecule of a star to be 1 body (eg. the sun) for far objects (eg. the earth). This is an approximation but I expect the result to be very good if the threshold is properly set. In fact, this kind of assumption is already done: molecules are far from being a point ;).

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't thought about using a reduced mass before, in my case gonna be a 'reduced' charge, not a common way to calculate in plasma physics but it is  worth trying.

Comment: There is also a generalization of what @JérômeRichard is alluding to, they are called fast multipole methods I think. So instead of just using the total charge at the centre of charge position, you can calculate corrections using multipole moments.

Comment: What I was referring is called [Barnes–Hut simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation) (quite usual in HPC). Despite the `log n` factor, such approach as the benefit of being simple to parallelize AFAIK, and it is also simple to understand. There is indeed the [Fast multipole method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method) mentioned by paleonix which appears to be faster (no `log n` factor) but also more complex to understand IMO (IDK for parallelization). It may make more sense (ie. more accurate) in plasma physics though (due to the EM coupling).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic version using shared memory to optimize the access pattern a bit.

```
#define KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE 256

__global__ void __launch_bounds__(KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE)
kernel(const double* x, const double* y, const double* z, int N,
       double k, double q, double* fake_out)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    /*
     * threads beyond the bound still participate in value fetching, so we cannot
     * return early
     */
    const bool active = i < N;
    double xi, yi, zi;
    if(active)
        xi = x[i], yi = y[i], zi = z[i];
    const double kqq = k * q * q;
    double Fx = 0., Fy = 0., Fz = 0.;
    __shared__ double xt[KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE];
    __shared__ double yt[KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE];
    __shared__ double zt[KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE];
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j += blockDim.x) {
        __syncthreads();
        const int thread_j = j + threadIdx.x;
        if(thread_j < N) {
            xt[threadIdx.x] = x[thread_j];
            yt[threadIdx.x] = y[thread_j];
            zt[threadIdx.x] = z[thread_j];
        }
        __syncthreads();
        for(int l = 0, M = min(KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE, N - j); l < M; ++l) {
            const double dx = xi - xt[l], dy = yi - yt[l], dz = zi - zt[l];
            // 1 / sqrt(dx*dx + dy+dy + dz*dz)
            const double rnorm = rnorm3d(dx, dy, dz);
            const double dr = rnorm * rnorm * rnorm;
            const double scale = kqq * dr;
            Fx += scale * dx;
            Fy += scale * dy;
            Fz += scale * dz;
        }
    }
    if(active)
        fake_out[i] = norm3d(Fx, Fy, Fz);
}
```

It's nothing fancy and it doesn't solve the inherent issues with the O(N²) runtime. I made the following changes

1. Get rid of the while loop. The loop counter was declared as `int i`. The maximum grid dimension in all CUDA devices is 2^31-1. Meaning we can always launch the entire grid with only one loop per thread.

Given the quadratic runtime, we have no chance of ever running such a huge grid, anyway. But if we did have one that is larger, just launch multiple kernels operating on subsets

2. Use shared memory to buffer blocks. I picked 256 as a fixed blocksize. That tends to work well. 512 may be another size that is worth experimenting with
3. The whole `dr` calculation can be folded into a single predefined math function
4. To get something that at least compiles into reasonable code, I added an output

### Double buffering

We can reduce the number of `__syncthreads()` that are required by using double buffering. However, that doubles the shared memory usage. Platforms that have only 64 kiB of shared memory will suffer limited occupancy. It requires benchmarking to see which version works better.

```
__global__ void __launch_bounds__(KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE)
kernel_dbuf(const double* x, const double* y, const double* z, int N,
            double k, double q, double* fake_out)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const bool active = i < N;
    double xi, yi, zi;
    if(active)
        xi = x[i], yi = y[i], zi = z[i];
    const double kqq = k * q * q;
    double Fx = 0., Fy = 0., Fz = 0.;
    __shared__ double xt[2][KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE];
    __shared__ double yt[2][KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE];
    __shared__ double zt[2][KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE];
    int dbuf = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < N; dbuf ^= 1, j += blockDim.x) {
        const int thread_j = j + threadIdx.x;
        if(thread_j < N) {
            xt[dbuf][threadIdx.x] = x[thread_j];
            yt[dbuf][threadIdx.x] = y[thread_j];
            zt[dbuf][threadIdx.x] = z[thread_j];
        }
        __syncthreads();
        for(int l = 0, M = min(KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE, N - j); l < M; ++l) {
            const double dx = xi - xt[dbuf][l];
            const double dy = yi - yt[dbuf][l];
            const double dz = zi - zt[dbuf][l];
            // 1 / sqrt(dx*dx + dy+dy + dz*dz)
            const double rnorm = rnorm3d(dx, dy, dz);
            const double dr = rnorm * rnorm * rnorm;
            const double scale = kqq * dr;
            Fx += scale * dx;
            Fy += scale * dy;
            Fz += scale * dz;
        }
    }
    if(active)
        fake_out[i] = norm3d(Fx, Fy, Fz);
}
```

Launch the kernel like this:

```
__host__ void
launch(const double* x, const double* y, const double* z, int N,
      double k, double q, double* fake_out, cudaStream_t stream)
{
    const int numBlocks = (N + KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE - 1) / KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE;
    kernel<<<numBlocks, KERNEL_BLOCKSIZE, 0, stream>>>(x, y, z, N, k, q, fake_out);
}
```

### Other thoughts

1. People have already commented on the inherent inefficiency of the algorithm
2. I guess there is a good reason why `k` and `q` are separate variables and you don't just pass a precomputed `k * q * q` to the kernel
3. Using doubles should always be a last resort when computing on a GPU, in my opinion. Possible avenues to reduce the precision, at least for parts of the algorithm:

- Replace the `dr` computation with one that is less prone to overflows. Like this:

```
float scale = 1.f / max(max(abs(dx), abs(dy)), abs(dz));
float rnorm = rnorm3df(dx * scale, dy * scale, dz * scale) * scale;
float dr = rnorm * rnorm * rnorm;
```

- Use Kahan summation for `Fx`, `Fy`, `Fz`
- Use double only for `Fx`, `Fy`, `Fz` but not `x`, `y`, `z` positions or other computations

Comment: I am wondering if shared memory is really much helpful here since data should be in the cache (as long as the version uses blocking), thread are reading broadcasted data and there are no inter-thread data communication. I expect a register blocking method to be significantly faster (possibly combined with shared memory if even needed).

Comment: For the float vs double, I think using float here is dangerous because MD codes deal with very small distances so cubic distances can quickly result in underflows. This is especially a problem since the OP appears to deals with plasma so the density is very small and so the standard deviation (SD) can be big (not to mention the cubic distance which make that much worse). Kahan summation is not very good when the SD is big and it would certainly defeat the benefit of using floats in term of speed (at least on server-side GPUs). It can make sense for DP though.